# Read barcode from a pdf file with React Native

Tags: react-native, pdf, barcode-scanner, open-with

I want to open a pdf file found in the phone/device storage with a React Native app and be able to read the barcode numbers found in the pdf itself.

I've seen some apps, many banking/financial ones, that let you open a bill in pdf format with the *"open with"* option of the phone (like shown in this example [here](https://www.inlovewithandroid.com/images/how-to-set-default-apps-in-Android.jpg)), in order to pay some bill.

Has anyone done this before with React Native? Can someone give me some hints/tips on how that can be accomplished with React Native?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which type of a barcode you want to scan? Can you split the functionalities into two steps - 1. converting a PDF into a series of images, and 2. reading the barcode from these images? And out of curiosity - which apps allow you to scan the bill?

Comment: @Cerovec The type is the [Interleaved 2 of 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaved_2_of_5). Yeah, some banking apps in Brazil have this feature, such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.banestes.rmb.mobile&hl=en) allowing you to open the pdf file with their app, going straight to the payment section afterwards (in between I believe the app scans the pdf looking for a valid barcode). 

This is what I want to implement in my app with React Native. Yeah, I thought about something along these lines as well, converting to an image before reading the barcode.